# Reformulate this without using scheme language

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I just read something in an algebraic geometry book that I am trying to understand. I don't know any scheme language yet so I am wondering if this is translatable into non-scheme language:

> For $v \in V$ the corresponding maximal ideal   $m_v := \{ f \in
>  \mathbb{C}[x] : f(v)=0\}$ contains all hypersurfaces which pass through <$v$> (the point in
>    $\mathbb{P}(V)$ spanned by $v$).  It's square $m_v^2$ defines a
>    scheme denoted by <$v$>$^2$ called a double point. A hypersurface is
>    singular at <$v$> iff it contains <$v$>$^2$.

I don't understand what 'it defines a scheme' means. Please don't try to explain me what a scheme is, I would much rather appreciate a workaround explanation of how <$v$>$^2$ is defined, so I can understand the 'A hypersurface is singular at <$v$> iff it contains <$v$>$^2$' part.

Edit: If it helps understanding I think this is working towards elementary statements about the tangential space at <$v$>.

Comment: If you are asking a question about a book you are working on, it is always a good idea to tell us what book it is, rather than just give a quotation. Someone familiar with the book will often be able to give you a much better answer than is possible based just on a quotation.

Comment: Even if we are not familiar with the book, quotations often lack too much context for us to properly explain them without going back to the book and looking it up.

Comment: Also the sentence is just saying that a hypersurface defined by a homogeneous ideal $I$ is singular at $\langle v \rangle$ if and only if $I\subseteq m_v^2$.